# Turning off auto white balance in vlc options

Tags: c#, vlc

i am using a wrapper to VLC from c#. I would like to turn the auto white balance off.

Is it possible and does anyone know the option switch?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: which wrapper are you using?

Comment: hi Bolu,I am using the nvlc wrapper that Roman Ginzburg (in codeproject)...

Comment: hi Soner, I believe it is a real question. As for what i have tried i have tried nothing because i have found nothing around to try. Also, i only wanted to know if it is theoretically possible to do so using an framework (like Roman's) after the image had been taken by the camera. As it is i found out that you can only adjust the white balancing directly in the camera/hardware.  cheers